# How can I get an accounts currency balance using eosjs

Tags: transactions, eosjs

In the new version of eosjs, the getCurrencyBalance() method is no longer supported. How can I still get the currency balance of an account using eosjs?

Comment: I think now you have to get the currency table of `eosio.token` as we did while we get the account balance  inside contract. Now you have to call the table action using eosjs.

Answer (score 4):

In eosjs v20.x, `getCurrencyBalance` has been renamed to [`get_currency_balance`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/e5ca122dc06c53fa5a92ce0188e73e2fc94cd9e2/src/eosjs-jsonrpc.ts#L95), and moved within the `Rpc` object.

You can use it like this...

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { JsonRpc } = require('eosjs');

// Instantiate a new JsonRpc object, with the Network Api Uri, and a request object
const rpc = new JsonRpc('https://api.kylin.alohaeos.com', { fetch });
// Request the balance, passing in the token contract, the account name, and the token symbol
rpc.get_currency_balance('eosio.token', 'eospaceioeos', 'EOS').then((balance) => console.log(balance));
```

Comment: it would be great to see an updated version of this answer

Comment: error jsonrpc not a constructor

Comment: This answer works, thanks a lot!